# How to know if using an ORM will not lead to poor performance?

Tags: orm

I plan to create a small online DD3 like game manager:

- Download Client and play peer to peer with friends
- online with everybody
- or simply create your characters sheet with it for home game.

There would be (very) basics grid and 2D "graphics". Mostly it would be used for the grid map and for characters sheets persistence . Also, I do not want to spend to much time on it.

I'm an experienced programmer. I'm also used to DB tuning, and stored procedures.
However those tasks are highly time consuming. I Plan to use and ORM.

However, I've seens many industrial project performing really poorly because of those. Most of the time the difference is outrageous. So here a re my points:

1. How to decide ( precise guideline/methods ) if an ORM will kill preformance of my apps? What parameters are the most important ( size? number of tables? number of queries?... )
2. Is ORM fine tuning not more time consuming at the end than simply odl school DB tuning?

Please be very precise in your answers. I'll take the time to read very carefully each of them and check for the facts and examples.

Comment: In my experience ORM tuning is a *lot* more expensive than "plain" DB tuning as you usually don't have a lot of possibilities to change the generated SQL

Comment: +1 for stored procedures.
If it is both slower and longer to tune...

Answer (score 0):

ORM will always perform worse (will be less optimized) then a correctly designed database. You will only gain in easier/quicker development if you don't like SQL and plan to move to another SQL engine. I would suggest not to use ORM if you are not planning in moving from one SQL engine to another. You could use it only if you really hate SQL.

How to decide:

1. You hate SQL: +1 for ORM.
2. You love objects: +1 for ORM.
3. Your don't want to use some non-SQL solution: +1 for ORM.
4. You won't need stats or any tables merging of many entities (tables/objects): +1 for ORM.
5. You plan to move to another DBMS in future: +1 for ORM (or at least some SQL framework).

You see it's not the problem of how many queries will run in your application, it's a problem of merging tables efficiently (and running in-efficient queries many times). Even merging two tables can be less efficient in ORM (for example ORM might use 3 tables when you only need one and ID from a relation table). And so yes - fine tuning ORM compared to SQL is a horror (you will end up writing in semi-SQL and even that will not give you the same level of control).

Comment: The main issue is about the trade off performance/devTime. 

`it's a problem of merging tables efficiently (and running in-efficient queries many times). Even merging two tables can be less efficient in ORM (for example ORM might use 3 tables when you only need one and ID from a relation table).`

Any example ?

`you will end up writing in semi-SQL and even that will not give you the same level of control`. That was the type of answer i was looking for... Few more like this and I go for stored procedures...

Comment: I don't remember exact example, but e.g. getting data of tags and ids of all topics assigned to them might be very hard. There would be two object: tags, topics and three tables: tags, topics_to_tags, topics. You only need two tables, but e.g. Hibernate will use three.